# How do I get the folder of the known file directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, working-directory

What command can I execute using python to find the folder of the file(the directory is known) using python?

For example, I have `"C:/Users/ExUser/Documents/Folder/Player/To-Do.txt"`, I just need the `"Player"` part.

Comment: `split('/')[-2]`?

Comment: @Guy it would be better to use `os.path` module or something similar.

Comment: [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [basename](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [dirname](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname),

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/ExUser/Documents/Folder/Player/To-Do.txt'
os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))
```

Or 
Simply

`path.split('/')[-2]`

Comment: Does the former or latter do the job faster?

Comment: @SF12Study I would recommend you to use the first method. because in some OS the path will have `\`. So try to write in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parent` property of a `pathlib.Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("C:/Users/ExUser/Documents/Folder/Player/To-Do.txt")
print(f'path.parent.as_posix(): {path.parent.as_posix()}')
```

Output:

```
path.parent.as_posix(): C:/Users/ExUser/Documents/Folder/Player
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem could be to use the library `os` as follows:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/folders')
os.system('ls')
```